# rails no error details on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having big problems with finding what is causing my rails app to return 500 internal error when I call a controller action. I tried setting the config.log_level = :debug in the production.rb environment, but rails won't write display or write any details about the error in the production.log.

If I run the same app and do the same action on my local machine in development mode, I don't get any error.

How should I reveal what is causing the error? I also tried using errorapp.com but no error will be reported there..

Thanks for help

Comment: where / how is it deployed? you should be able to get some logging!

Comment: You should be seeing exceptions in the production log even if your log_level is set to info

Comment: Could you post the lines you are seeing the production log when you hit the action that causes 500?

Comment: is it in Heroku., run the command "heroku logs"., to see what are the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use the exception_notification gem [link](http://smartinez87.github.io/exception_notification/)
in all my rails apps. When configured with the mail settings it will email you when an exception occurs with the error info.